# How to direct to another page in java after providing download option

Tags: java, servlets

I am providing download feature for file which I am generating. 
The code to provide download option is

```
ServletOutputStream sos=response.getOutputStream();
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename=" + "Timesheet.pdf" ); 
sos.write();
```

once this code has been executed successfully it means that response is already used.
So when I tries to use response.sendRedirect() or RequestDispatcher it shows me exception that response is already commited.

So can anyone help me how I direct my execution to another page after providing download..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are experiencing is the correct functionality of Servlets. That is once after Committing a Response (Sending the First line with HTTP Headers) you can not do anything else.

But what you can do is, do the other way around like the Eclipse Download page or Sourceforge Download page does.

First you can show a page which says Thanks for downloading or whatever and it can have a link to click and download or a javascript which will download automatically by calling your download Servlet.